# Is it possible to put a white border to the text in a terminal window?

Tags: macos, mac, terminal, themes

I use the terminal a lot, and having the same terminal design gets boring. I set the background to those cool default desktop images, and every terminal window is a random image.

The text is hard to read on certain space themed images, so it would be nice to have my black text surrounded by a white border in order to be legible.

Here is an example and setup image: [image]

Is there some way to add an extension to the terminal, like some kind of custom themes? I did not find anything in the settings.

I think I will need to add some kind of code, like a plugin or extension to add this functionality. Where would the terminal source code be?

EDIT:
Ok, I have discovered that you can export terminal "profiles", which have a .terminal extension. It is saved as plist. Xcode can view this, if you change the file type from .terminal to .plist.
Here is the almost decoded data, I have yet to figure out what the groups of numbers decode to:

```
{
    "BackgroundAlphaInactive" = 0.2501997514204545;
    BackgroundBlur = 0.619873046875;
    "BackgroundBlurInactive" = 0;
    BackgroundColor = <62706c69 73743030 d4010203 04050615 16582476 65727369 6f6e5824 6f626a65 63747359 24617263 68697665 72542474 6f701200 0186a0a3 07080f55 246e756c 6cd3090a 0b0c0d0e 554e5352 47425c4e 53436f6c 6f725370 61636556 24636c61 73734b31 20312031 20302e38 35001001 8002d210 1112135a 24636c61 73736e61 6d655824 636c6173 73657357 4e53436f 6c6f72a2 1214584e 534f626a 6563745f 100f4e53 4b657965 64417263 68697665 72d11718 54726f6f 74800108 111a232d 32373b41 484e5b62 6e707277 828b9396 9fb1b4b9 00000000 00000101 00000000 00000019 00000000 00000000 00000000 000000bb>;
    "BackgroundImageBookmark" = <62706c69 73743030 d4010203 04050614 15582476 65727369 6f6e5824 6f626a65 63747359 24617263 68697665 72542474 6f701200 0186a0a3 07080d55 246e756c 6cd2090a 0b0c574e 532e6461 74615624 636c6173 734f1102 b8626f6f 6bb80200 00000004 10300000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00e40100 00070000 00010100 004c6962 72617279 00100000 00010100 00446573 6b746f70 20506963 74757265 73080000 00010600 00040000 00140000 00080000 00040300 004c03c4 02000000 00080000 00040300 007b16ca 02000000 00080000 00010600 003c0000 004c0000 00080000 00000400 0041b7ce f2b60000 00180000 00010200 00020000 00000000 000f0000 00000000 00000000 00000000 000c0000 00010100 004d6163 696e746f 73682048 44080000 00040300 00008081 3d740000 00080000 00000400 0041b411 739c0000 00240000 00010100 00364633 41334446 392d3444 30392d33 4436422d 39433741 2d424531 46423937 41393238 31180000 00010200 00810000 00010008 00ef1700 00010008 00000000 00000000 00010000 00010100 002f0000 00000000 00010500 00aa0000 00010200 00336531 37333637 62663666 33623162 30376665 66346563 62616532 36303334 61643234 61323863 643b3030 30303030 30303b30 30303030 3030303b 30303030 30303030 30303030 30303230 3b636f6d 2e617070 6c652e61 70702d73 616e6462 6f782e72 6561642d 77726974 653b3030 30303030 30313b30 31303030 3030323b 30303030 30303030 30326361 31363762 3b2f6c69 62726172 792f6465 736b746f 70207069 63747572 65730000 009c0000 00feffff ff010000 00000000 000c0000 00041000 002c0000 00000000 00051000 005c0000 00000000 00101000 007c0000 00000000 00401000 006c0000 00000000 00022000 001c0100 00000000 00102000 009c0000 00000000 00112000 00d00000 00000000 00122000 00b00000 00000000 00132000 00c00000 00000000 00202000 00fc0000 00000000 00302000 00280100 00000000 0080f000 00300100 00000000 008002d2 0e0f1011 5a24636c 6173736e 616d6558 24636c61 73736573 5d4e534d 75746162 6c654461 7461a310 1213564e 53446174 61584e53 4f626a65 63745f10 0f4e534b 65796564 41726368 69766572 d1161754 726f6f74 80010008 0011001a 0023002d 00320037 003b0041 0046004e 00550311 03130318 0323032c 033a033e 0345034e 03600363 03680000 00000000 02010000 00000000 00180000 00000000 00000000 00000000 036a>;
    "BackgroundSettingsForInactiveWindows" = YES;
    BlinkText = YES;
    CursorBlink = YES;
    CursorColor = <62706c69 73743030 d4010203 04050615 16582476 65727369 6f6e5824 6f626a65 63747359 24617263 68697665 72542474 6f701200 0186a0a3 07080f55 246e756c 6cd3090a 0b0c0d0e 554e5352 47425c4e 53436f6c 6f725370 61636556 24636c61 73734f10 10302031 20302e39 37313932 31393238 00100180 02d21011 12135a24 636c6173 736e616d 65582463 6c617373 6573574e 53436f6c 6f72a212 14584e53 4f626a65 63745f10 0f4e534b 65796564 41726368 69766572 d1171854 726f6f74 80010811 1a232d32 373b4148 4e5b6275 77797e89 929a9da6 b8bbc000 00000000 00010100 00000000 00001900 00000000 00000000 00000000 0000c2>;
    CursorType = 1;
    Font = <62706c69 73743030 d4010203 04050618 19582476 65727369 6f6e5824 6f626a65 63747359 24617263 68697665 72542474 6f701200 0186a0a4 07081112 55246e75 6c6cd409 0a0b0c0d 0e0f1056 4e535369 7a65584e 5366466c 61677356 4e534e61 6d655624 636c6173 73234026 00000000 00001010 80028003 5d4d656e 6c6f2d52 6567756c 6172d213 1415165a 24636c61 73736e61 6d655824 636c6173 73657356 4e53466f 6e74a215 17584e53 4f626a65 63745f10 0f4e534b 65796564 41726368 69766572 d11a1b54 726f6f74 80010811 1a232d32 373c424b 525b6269 72747678 868b969f a6a9b2c4 c7cc0000 00000000 01010000 00000000 001c0000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00ce>;
    FontAntialias = YES;
    FontHeightSpacing = 1;
    FontWidthSpacing = 1.004;
    Linewrap = YES;
    "ProfileCurrentVersion" = 2.04;
    "ShowActiveProcessInTitle" = YES;
    "ShowCommandKeyInTitle" = YES;
    "ShowShellCommandInTitle" = YES;
    ShowTTYNameInTitle = NO;
    "ShowWindowSettingsNameInTitle" = NO;
    TextBoldColor = <62706c69 73743030 d4010203 04050615 16582476 65727369 6f6e5824 6f626a65 63747359 24617263 68697665 72542474 6f701200 0186a0a3 07080f55 246e756c 6cd3090a 0b0c0d0e 554e5352 47425c4e 53436f6c 6f725370 61636556 24636c61 73734f10 29302e30 32333039 30333839 30362030 2e333735 33363039 30333520 302e3034 36393839 35373439 33001001 8002d210 1112135a 24636c61 73736e61 6d655824 636c6173 73657357 4e53436f 6c6f72a2 1214584e 534f626a 6563745f 100f4e53 4b657965 64417263 68697665 72d11718 54726f6f 74800108 111a232d 32373b41 484e5b62 8e909297 a2abb3b6 bfd1d4d9 00000000 00000101 00000000 00000019 00000000 00000000 00000000 000000db>;
    UseBrightBold = YES;
    name = User;
    type = "Window Settings";
    useOptionAsMetaKey = YES;
    "warnOnShellCloseAction" = 2;
}
```

EDIT 2:
Progress! I came across https://georgegarside.com/blog/decode-data-plist/ and it told me what to do. I was able to convert the number data to Base64, then using an online decoder I was able to get a .bin file. Then, with text mate, it had a feature to decode it into an old property list-type text. I now have the following font data:

```
{
    "$archiver" = NSKeyedArchiver;
    "$objects" =     (
        "$null",
                {
            "$class" = "<CFKeyedArchiverUID 0x7fe0f3c147e0 [0x7fff72c45ed0]>{value = 3}";
            NSName = "<CFKeyedArchiverUID 0x7fe0f3c14990 [0x7fff72c45ed0]>{value = 2}";
            NSSize = 11;
            NSfFlags = 16;
        },
        "Menlo-Regular",
                {
            "$classes" =             (
                NSFont,
                NSObject
            );
            "$classname" = NSFont;
        }
    );
    "$top" =     {
        root = "<CFKeyedArchiverUID 0x7fe0f3c14e40 [0x7fff72c45ed0]>{value = 1}";
    };
    "$version" = 100000;
}
```

I wonder how I can edit this to give me a border...